# Bind action parameters in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a submit button that will dispatch an action. The action's payload is the post data that will be sent to an API. Currently I use `bindActionCreators` in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    actions:  bindActionCreators(FormActions, dispatch)
});
```

then in my component I bind `onClick` to the submit action:

```
<input type="submit" onClick={() => this.props.actions.submit(this.props.postData)} />
```

I don't like that I have to give this component the post data in `mapStateToProps`. I'd prefer to just give the component an action that already has the post data binded to the submit function so it's usage would look like this:

```
<input type="submit" onClick={this.props.submit} />
```

Is this possible? I don't have access to the state in `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: If the data is already in the store, then why not just read it from the reducer?

Comment: Does the data come from the parent props, or mapStatetoProps?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand  Data comes from `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: @ZekeDroid the data is needed in an API middleware, although I guess I could grab it off the state in the middleware. I would just have to stop using the createAPIAction library I was using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a third argument called [mergeProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) in `connect` method of `react-redux` which is supposed to be used in cases like one you just described. In your case you can do something like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ postData: ... });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions:  bindActionCreators(FormActions, dispatch)
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps) => ({
  submit: () => dispatchProps.actions.submit(stateProps.postData),
});

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(Component);
```

Note that Component will not receive `actions` nor `postData`, just `submit`.

Comment: Note that use of `mergeProps` is generally discouraged because it's bad for performance.  It will re-create functions every time the store changes, thus causing the component to re-render every time.

Comment: @markerikson returning function prop from `mergeProps` differs in no way from returning it from `mapStateToProps`: to prevent re-rendering in both cases you have to make sure that you are returning the same function instance between the invocation. At least that what I can conclude from [that line of code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/f892ec00d7e92ff7afb21498276472f0e3b000c5/src/connect/mergeProps.js#L18). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Couple things. First, it'd be `mapDispatch`, not `mapState`. Second, if `mergeProps` is passed in, and you declare a func in `mergeProps`, it'd be a new function reference _every time `mergeProps` runs_, whereas `mapDispatch` is only run once at comp init (or when props change, if two-arg form of `mapDispatch` is used).   (I could be wrong, but 99% sure that's the actual behavior.)